# pySpark withColumn with a function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe which has 2 columns: `account_id` and `email_address`, now I want to add one more column `updated_email_address` which i call some function on `email_address` to get the `updated_email_address`. here is my code:

```
def update_email(email):
  print("== email to be updated: " + email)
  today = datetime.date.today()
  updated = substring(email, -8, 8) + str(today.strftime('%m')) + str(today.strftime('%d')) + "_updated"
  return updated

df.withColumn('updated_email_address', update_email(df.email_address))
```

but the result showed `updated_email_address` column as null:

```
+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
|account_id     |email_address |updated_email_address|
+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
|123456gd7tuhha |abc@test.com  |null           |
|djasevneuagsj1 |cde@test.com  |null           |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

inside the function `updated_email` it printed out:

```
Column<b'(email_address + == email to be udpated: )'>
```

also it showed the df's column data type as:

```
dfData:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
account_id:string
email_address:string
updated_email_address:double
```

why is `updated_email_address` column type of double?

Comment: you need to use an UDF (user defined function).
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling a Python function with `Column` type. 
You have to create udf from `update_email` and then use it:

```
update_email_udf = udf(update_email)
```

However, I'd suggest you to not use UDF fot such transformation, you could do it using only Spark built-in functions (UDFs are known for bad performance) :

```
df.withColumn('updated_email_address',
              concat(substring(col("email_address"), -8, 8), date_format(current_date(), "ddMM"), lit("_updated"))
             ).show()
```

You can find [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html) all Spark SQL built-in functions.

Answer (score 5):

Well thanks to you I got to relearn something I forgot in my spark class

You can't call directly your custom functions with WithColumn, you need to use UserDefinedFunctions (UDF)

Here is a quick example of how I got a custom function to work with your dataframe (StringType is the return type of the function)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def update_email(email):
  return email+"aaaa"
#df.dtypes

my_udf = udf(lambda x: update_email(x), StringType())

df.withColumn('updated_email_address', my_udf(df.email_address) ).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call direct python function with pyspark library to achieve the output. Below is the code snippet

def update_email(email):
print("== email to be updated: " + email)
return F.concat(F.substring(F.col(email), -8, 8),F.date_format(F.current_timestamp(),"yyyy MM dd"), F.lit("_updated"))

df=spark.read.format('csv').option('delimiter','|').option('header','true').load('sample4.csv')
df=df.withColumn("updatedemail",update_email("email")).show(truncate=False)

== email to be updated: email
+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|acct_id       |email        |updatedemail              |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+strong text
|123456gd7tuhha|abc@gmail.com|mail.com2022 05 14_updated|
|djasevneuagsj1|def@gmail.com|mail.com2022 05 14_updated|`dsjf`
+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).