# Pyspark - how to generate same random numbers for each float value of a DataFrame column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, random, pyspark

I created a function to generate random values in a given range for DF columns.

```
test_df = self.spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'metric1', 10.5), (2, 'metric2', 20.7), (3, 'metric3', 30.1)], ['id', 'metric', 'score'])

def generate_rand_value(col: Column) -> Column:
    lower = col - (col * RANGE)
    upper = col + (col * RANGE)
    return random.uniform(lower, upper)
```

Then I decided to modify it to generate a fixed number for each column value in a range using `seed`:

```
def generate_fixed_rand_value(column: Column):
    random.seed(5)
    return random.randint(column, 10)
```

This results in an error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Column'`. What will be the right way to call the function for generating fixed float numbers for each column value? Or maybe there is a more suitable approach for that?

I call the function like this:

```
def parse_cols(df, cols: list):
    for col_name in cols:
        df = df.withColumn(col_name, generate_fixed_rand_value(F.col(col_name)))
    return df
```

Comment: did you register your function as a udf?

Comment: Actually no, I wasn't planning to use a UDF as I did with the `generate_rand_value` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got lucky with random.uniform because the implementation in python is such that the operands are used inline with pyspark syntax. Refer below from the source code - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/random.py

```
def uniform(self, a, b):
    "Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding."
     return a + (b-a) * self.random()
```

so when your use random.uniform inside withColumn , for example  `test=df_in.withColumn('tst',random.uniform(col('x'),col('y'))` , it translates to  `df_in.withColumn('tst',(col('x')+(col('x')-col('y'))*<some_randomnumber>)` which is an allowed syntax in pyspark

But for randitnt, somehow it ends up executing this function

```
def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, _int=int):
    """Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).
    This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
    endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.
    """

    # This code is a bit messy to make it fast for the
    # common case while still doing adequate error checking.
    istart = _int(start)
    if istart != start:
        raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()")
```

As you can see, there is a check to ensure that the arguments are integer, hence you get an error. However when you make your function a udf, then it is executed row by row, hence only integers are passed and the function works.

So in your function generate_fixed_rand_value - you can replace randint() with uniform() function and it will work. Just as a hint - you can also use uniform() directly in withColumn() and a seperate function is not needed

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import random
random.seed(5)
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(10,7.5,14),(5,1.2,4),(9,7.5,10),(2,1.2,90),(10,2.0,30),(3,5.5,11)],schema=['val1','x','y'])
tst_res1 = tst.withColumn("random_number",random.uniform(F.col('x'),10))
```

results:

```
+----+---+---+-----------------+
|val1|  x|  y|    random_number|
+----+---+---+-----------------+
|  10|7.5| 14|9.057254237224255|
|   5|1.2|  4|6.681534915029378|
|   9|7.5| 10|9.057254237224255|
|   2|1.2| 90|6.681534915029378|
|  10|2.0| 30|6.983213559117615|
|   3|5.5| 11|8.303057627003659|
+----+---+---+-----------------+
```

There are fixed random numbers per value in the column x. If you need it for other columns, you can use a for loop or use a reduce function.

Incase  you need a random number between a percentage of a particular column replace the last line with this:

```
tst_res1 = tst.withColumn("random_number",random.uniform((F.col('x')-(0.25*F.col('x'))),(F.col('x')+(0.25*F.col('x')))))The results:

+----+---+---+------------------+
|val1|  x|  y|     random_number|
+----+---+---+------------------+
|  10|7.5| 14|  8.66794067791819|
|   5|1.2|  4|1.3868705084669106|
|   9|7.5| 10|  8.66794067791819|
|   2|1.2| 90|1.3868705084669106|
|  10|2.0| 30| 2.311450847444851|
|   3|5.5| 11|  6.35648983047334|
+----+---+---+------------------+
```

Comment: But I'm using `generate_rand_value`, which is a generic function inside the withColumn the same way, and it's working correctly.

Comment: Sorry, for a  premature answer, I have always thought generic custom functions cannot be used in df. also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317300/pyspark-withcolumn-with-a-function turns out that random.uniform() works fine !! For me this is the anomaly behavior. The error that we get  for random.int() should be the expected behavior. Must look in deep how random.uniform() is implemented in pytthon

Comment: just an additional info , for random.uniform also this works : ````tst_res1 = tst.withColumn("isdt",random.uniform(F.col('x'),F.col('y')))````

Comment: let me know if the updated answer helps. cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear. But my initial question was on how to generate same random numbers for each float value of a DataFrame column? Randint doesn't seem to deal with floats

Comment: but you have used randint inside your function generate_fixed_rand_value ? you need to replace it with random.uniform(), then it will work

Comment: Yes, because this was my attempt to generate fixed random numbers in a certain range from a column's value `random.randint(column, 10)`. And currently I'm not sure how to use it for floats

Comment: that's the problem. The code i have shown in the answer belongs to random.randint() implemenation and it need an integer. the same is not the case for uniform - you can use ````tst_res1 = tst.withColumn("isdt",random.uniform(F.col('x'),10))```` this will work
just change the column names

Comment: Using random.uniform as you showed is a great catch. But when I try `df.withColumn(col_name, random.uniform(F.col(col_name), 0.25))` it doesn't seem to generate a random number within +/-25% from the F.col(col_name) value. If it's possible, that will solve my problem. The only way I see for now is counting upper/lower bounds as shown in my question. But this requires a custom function

Comment: just updated the answer to show the usage of uniform for both the ways, to generate a random number within a fixed number or a percentage of values, check it out